# What does an input string of epsilon mean?

Tags: finite-automata

I am currently reading Introduction to the Theory of Computation (Sipser), and after introducing epsilon labeled transition arrows, the book shows the following NFA:

[image]

I was following it until I read the following :

> Practice with it to satisfy yourself that it accepts the strings ϵ, a, baba and baa...

What does an input string of ϵ mean?

Comment: It's the empty string, so a string of length zero. I'm sure the text explains it, just read it carefully.

Comment: @Juho - You're right - it is explained... Just a little hidden away, took me quite a while to find it - thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of NFAs, $\epsilon$ marks state transitions that do not consume input. These transitions thus express the non-determinism of the automaton.

When discussing the *acceptance* of $\epsilon$, the symbol marks the empty string (this is equivalent to the condition that an accepting state is reachable by a sequence of $\epsilon$-transitions from the start state). to avoid confusion, some authors use a different symbol for the empty string (often $\lambda$).